# Default fallback for C++ template functions using enable_if

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I want to write a C++ mechanism, where different instantiations of a function are called if a given class `Param` is derived from a certain base class.

This works pretty nicely with `std::is_base_of` and `std::enable_if`.

However, I would like to have a "default version" of this `doStuff()` function that is called for "every other class".
This would basically work by doing something like "if Param is not derived from A and if not derived from B", but I wonder whether there is a more elegant solution.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class X {};

class Y : public X {};

class Other {};

template <typename Param, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, Param>::value, bool> = true>
void doStuff() {std::cout << "Base A" << std::endl;};

template <typename Param, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<X, Param>::value, bool> = true>
void doStuff() {std::cout << "Base X" << std::endl;};


int main()
{
    doStuff<B>();
    doStuff<Y>();
    // doStuff<Other>(); this is neither derived from B and Y, so call the default case
}
```

The solution should work with C++14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `std:::enable_if`, you will have to provide a 3rd SFINAE'd overload that handles the default conditions which are not handled by the other overloads, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class X {};

class Y : public X {};

class Other {};

template <typename Param, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, Param>::value, bool> = true>
void doStuff() { std::cout << "Base A" << std::endl; }

template <typename Param, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<X, Param>::value, bool> = true>
void doStuff() { std::cout << "Base X" << std::endl; }

template <typename Param, std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_base_of<A, Param>::value || std::is_base_of<X, Param>::value), bool> = true>
void doStuff() { std::cout << "Something else" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    doStuff<B>(); // prints "Base A"
    doStuff<Y>(); // prints "Base X"
    doStuff<Other>(); // prints "Something else"
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/YqNZct)

That being said, in C++17 and later, you can use `if constexpr` instead, which is cleaner than using SFINAE in this situation, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class X {};

class Y : public X {};

class Other {};

template <typename Param>
void doStuff() {
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<A, Param>)
        std::cout << "Base A" << std::endl;
    else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<X, Param>)
        std::cout << "Base X" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Something else" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doStuff<B>(); // prints "Base A"
    doStuff<Y>(); // prints "Base X"
    doStuff<Other>(); // prints "Something else"
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Zk0j88kPO)

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for some simpler solution for C++14 (that scales well with more cases), but this will do for now. The C++17 solution however looks really elegant, I'll definitely keep that in mind when the code is transferred to C++17!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can use C++17 or later use constexpr, a lot more readable then SFINAE

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

class X {};
class Y : public X {};

class Other {};

template<typename type_t>
void doStuff()
{ 
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<A,type_t>)
    {
        std::cout << "Base A\n";
        
    }
    else
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<X, type_t>)
    {
        std::cout << "Base X\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Other\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    doStuff<B>();
    doStuff<Y>();
    doStuff<Other>(); //this is neither derived from B and Y, so call the default case

    return 0;
}
```